# Did Ben Gurion say this about conquering Palestinian land?

Tags: quotes, israel, palestine

I'm watching a video about the Israel/Palestine situation (supposedly from a reputable source), yet the video so far seem filled with inaccuracies and bias. For the record I'm not a member of either side either ethnically or religiously. It seems to me Abby Martin the journalist is doing her best to blacken the Zionists. The claim is that Ben Gurion (the first prime minister of Israel) said the following about the settlements in about the 1920s and 1930s:

> "We were not just working--we were conquering, conquering, conquering
>   land. We were a company of conquistadores."

[Link to point in video](https://youtu.be/BT5L4YU_Fl4?t=6m45s)

When I do a search for sections of this quote it worries me both that there aren't many results, and that Twitter usually comes up among the first results.

Also, she says Theodore Herzl was an atheist when I've discovered he most likely was not. She says that the Balfour Declaration was issued by a small group of British Lords, whereas when I look it up I read that it was issued by the British government. Many things considered together make me suspicious of her prejudice. Also it has an ominous soundtrack playing in the background. I don't think I can take this person seriously, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I don't think many people would call Martin a "reputable source" (considering eg her support of 9/11 conspiracy theories or her past work for Russian propaganda outlets), and her current work seems highly biased. But even though this isn't a reputable source, it still establishes a notable claim (we don't need good sources for that, only notable ones).

Comment: @tim I didn't about her other work that you mentioned. I'm glad I said "supposedly" reputable source, because I was already in doubt.

Comment: @Avery There's also a letter by Ben Gurion talking about to "expel the Arabs", though it's contested whether this could have meant "not expel the Arabs", based on whether an edit or deletion was made. I don't know if there's any basis for the the refutal.

Comment: I agree with @tim. I mean, the description of the video is: “The Empire Files looks at the long history of Zionist colonization, expansion and expulsion of Palestine’s indigenous inhabitants.” It’s even called “the Empire Files.” Hardly a neutral, or perhaps even objective, description. Further, Telesur is government-funded (always a dodgy prospect when it comes to news). It’s not without good programming, but it’s a very slanted and occasionally propagandistic source.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I've just seen Telesur isn't well respected generally. About your government funded media always being dodgy comment, I'm just trying to understand, because as far as I know corporate interests aren't entirely in the best interests of the general people. Do you think the BBC is more biased than Fox News for example?

Comment: @Zebrafish - Nothings’s *guaranteed*. Fox News is indeed more biased than  the BBC. But in my experience, yes, heavy government funding tends to be worse for journalistic integrity than large private profits (though one could argue neither’s good). But more to the point, a new organization being founded by a government *can* be a sign that it’s designed at least in part as propaganda. It’s an invitation to look more closely.

Comment: @Zebrafish BBC is *not government funded*. It’s strictly independent. That said, it’s well established (and backed up by studies) that BBC has a clear pro-government bias, despite mandatory editorial impartiality

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Of course it's government funded. The majority of the funding comes from the government payments to the BBC originating from public taxes.  What news media outlets aren't biased in your opinion? I'm asking out of genuine curiosity here, because I can't seem to get a consensus.

Comment: @Zebrafish That’s a fundamental misunderstanding. The BBC is (mostly) *publicly* funded (with some funds coming from commercial revenue). It is *not* government funded. The distinction is crucial, because it influences who has a say: RT and Telesur are controlled by the government. [BBC isn’t.](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/27285) — As for bias, of course every news outlet is biased. But the BBC *claims* it isn’t, because its charter forbids it.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I never said BBC is government owned. Could you explain how it's not government funded if it's funded by public taxes? Also it's partially funded directly by the government's Foreign Office.

Comment: @Zebrafish the government is whoever happens to be in power, and they are not funding the BBC. The BBC is funded by public money _independently_ from whoever won the last elections. That is a major difference with an organisation that receives funding from or thanks to the specific party in power at a given moment.

Comment: @oerkelens That's a narrower meaning of government. The government can also mean the state regardless of which party is ruling. The public contributions go to the government's Department of Culture et al, and through exercise of the Appropriations Act then gets issued to the BBC no matter which government is in power. If someone could explain why it's not government funded if it's funded by the public's taxes, I'd be grateful. Leaving aside the fact that it receives direct funding from the Foreign Office.

Comment: Just in case there are any doubts that the contributions are a tax, they've been defined as such in 2006, "the licence fee is a compulsory payment which is not paid solely for access to BBC services".

Comment: @Zebrafish Look up [hypothecated tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothecated_tax). In a nutshell, the TV license fee is paid as a tax purely for legal and administrative purposes (e.g. to make non-payment is legally tax evasion). Compare this to the German church tax, which is also a proper tax, raised by the tax authority, but delivered to a church body. Yet nobody would claim that this means the church is government funded (at least not through this money). The government, then, acts purely as an intermediary. This is fundamentally different from other tax-paid endeavours.

Comment: @Zebrafish And let’s not lose sight of what we’re discussing here: we’re discussing the funding specifically *in the context over who retains editorial control*. Telesur, etc.: government. BBC: not government. Everything else is a distraction, so let’s stop talking about it.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I'm arguing the misuse of terminology. It's an equivocation to say that a hypothecated tax levied by the government is public funds but not government funds, it's both. Car registration fees may go entirely to maintaining roads, you can't say it's public funded and not government funded, it's both. Your argument is basically that a tax revenue set aside to be spent for a particular service is not government funds. You can distinguish a hypothecated tax from generalised tax, but they're still government revenue and spending.

Comment: @Zebrafish Likewise. And to avoid misusing terminology, there’s a distinction between “publicly funded”, which implies independence from government, and “government funded”, which does not. This distinction is far from universally applied (alas, so many problems would vanish if we only agreed on definitions all the time) but *in the context of Obie2.0’s comment*, it was clear which was meant. Your reply shows that there’s a need for this distinction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75623/discussion-between-zebrafish-and-konrad-rudolph).

Answer (score 53):

#### TL;DR:

The words of this out of context quote are correct, the origin for this quote in terms of authorship are correct, the origin in terms of attributed time are not correct.
**Both, misattribution of time and lack of context, make this essentially correct quote problematic.**

#### Source

According to David Ben Gurion's 1954 book [*Rebirth and Destiny of Israel*](https://www.questia.com/library/1326180/rebirth-and-destiny-of-israel) he wrote an essay **in 1917** called "In Judea and Galilee", in which he wrote about Zionist settlers:

> "We were not just working--we were conquering, conquering, conquering land. We were a company of conquistadores."

More easily accessible  in [Joseph Schechla: "Forced eviction as an increment of demographic manipulation", Environment and Urbanization, Vol 6, Issue 1, 1994.](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/095624789400600109)

#### Context

Since this quote is often used in anti-Semitic contexts or other undesirable venues, it seems quite necessary to point out that while the quote is correct, although wrongly attributed concerning the exact date, the quote does not reflect the reality of 1917 at the time in the land and might need further context and explanation. The context is that a nationalistic (zionist) warringly and worryingly romanticising Ben-Gurion militarises Jewish settlement struggles, both against the harsh nature of the land as well previous inhabitants. This martial sounding and heroic language is typical for the time of writing for many authors and represents an invitation for misunderstandings. Which of these struggles, against "nature" or "natives" are most emphasised are up to debate, but over time his attitudes and actual policies changed.

> The land, he believed, must be conquered by the toil and sweat of Jewish pioneers, not by force of arms.
>
> <sub>From: David Landau: "Ben-Gurion: A Political Life", Schocken Books: New York, 2011.</sub>

This much less aggressive stance is evidenced in praxis later:

> Allon’s support for such a conquest, which would have delivered into the hands of the tiny Israel of 1949 the same West Bank Arab population that it found so hard to digest – nay, that it was unable to digest – twenty and forty years later, was very probably one of the reasons for Ben-Gurion’s refusal to appoint Allon and others of like mind to key positions in the post-1948 Israel Defense Forces.[…]
> At the end of the war, when Yigal Allon, who represented the younger generation of commanders that had grown up in the war, demanded the conquest of the West Bank up to the Jordan River as the natural, defensible border of the state, Ben-Gurion refused. He recognized that the IDF was militarily strong enough to carry out the conquest, but he believed that the young state should not bite off more than it had already chewed.[…]
> At the same time, Ben-Gurion was concerned that if Israel attacked Jordan, a European power, Britain, might intervene. He had no territorial aspirations: “At this stage we are not short of territory, but of Jews. And conquest of additional territory will not add Jews, but Arabs,” he wrote to a young man who proposed that he take the West Bank.
>
> <sub>From: Shlomo Aronson: "David Ben-Gurion and the Jewish Renaissance", Cambridge University Press: Cambridge, New York, 2011.</sub>

This realpolitik approach is evidenced almost as early as the quote in question:

> In 1918, David Ben-Gurion explained:
>
> > The true aim and real capacity of Zionism are not to conquer what has already been conquered (e.g., land cultivated by Arabs), but to settle in those places where the present inhabitants of the land have not established themselves and are unable to do so.
>
> <sub>From  (Ben-Gurion 1973, written in 1918 and first published in *Der Yiddisher Kempfer*), cited from: [Daniel E. Orenstein: "Zionist and Israeli Perspectives on Population Growth and Envirnomental Impact in Palestine and Israel"](http://orenstein.net.technion.ac.il/files/2017/11/Orenstein_2013_Population_ChapterBook.pdf),  In: Orenstein, D.E., Miller, C. and A. Tal (eds.): "Between Ruin and Restoration: Chapters in Israeli Environmental History", University of Pittsburgh Press: Pittsburgh, 2013.</sub>

To determine the source of this claim and quote it might be useful to watch the video from the question just a few seconds longer and wait for the next quote [attributed to Ben-Gurion](https://youtu.be/BT5L4YU_Fl4?t=434):

> "We must expel Arabs and take their places"

Then compare this to [Wikipedia's version](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/David_Ben-Gurion#Quotes):

> > "We do not wish, we do not need to expel the Arabs and take their place. All our aspirations are built upon the assumption — proven throughout all our activity in the Land — that there is enough room in the country for ourselves and the Arabs."
>
> Letter to his son Amos (5 October 1937), as quoted in Teveth, Shabtai, Ben Gurion: The Burning Ground; and Karsh, Efraim (2000), Fabricating Israeli History: The 'New Historians'; this has been extensively misquoted as "[We] must expel Arabs and take their places" after appearing in this form in Morris, Benny (1987), The Birth of the Palestinian Refugee Problem, 1947–1949, Cambridge University Press, p. 25.

Comment: Nice answer. If I understand well, the quote was written in 1917, so the claim is partially false when it pretends it would be "*about the settlements in about the 1920s and 1930s*".

Comment: @Evarglo Well, in the video it attributed to Ben Gurion "in the early days of settlement", the time period the video was covering at that point, as far as I can tell is the 20s and 30s. I believe 1917 would fairly cover the early days of settlement, so I'm not sure it's so false.

Comment: "*The context is that a nationalistic (zionist) warringly and worryingly romanticising Ben-Gurion militarises Jewish settlement struggles,*" Can you please clarify this phrase?

Comment: "Rebirth and Destiny of Israel" is Ben Gurion's essays as edited and translated from Hebrew under the supervision of Mordekhai Nurock.

Comment: I guess Abby Martin will use your post to prove her right. Well, only your first sentence, of course. No need to bore anyone with a tl;dr version.

Comment: Even more condensed TL;DR: Yes, he said it.  No, it wasn't about Palestinian land; it was about "conquering" uncooperative Israeli land and making it livable.

Comment: @Zebrafish one comment, "the early days of settlement" was not really in 1917, though it was extant for a few hundred years it really started en masse in mid-1800's (due to pogroms and being chased out of other countries, of course). Though I guess "early days" depends on what timescale you use :-)